# Is $(\sin x)^2$ a square function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is square of trigononetric function a square function or simply trigometric function? We know that $f(x)=x^2$ a square function then $f(\sin x)=(\sin x)^2$ square function.

Comment: No, $f(x) = \sin^2(x)$ is not a square function.  A square function is a function which, when graphed on a coordinate plane, produces a graph which is always a square, regardless of the input.  For example, $g(x) = x^2$ is a square function.

Comment: It is a composition of the square function (algebraic) and the sine (trigonometric) function. When combining or composing two different *types* of functions it may not meet the definition of one or the other.

Comment: Writing a function as $f(some\ kind\ of\ input)$ and saying that function is basically the same type as $f$ is both misleading and erroneous.  The "some kind of input" already putting the input through a function and is not straight input.  Consdier $f(x) = x^3 + 7$ and $some\ kind\ of\ input = g(x) = \sqrt[3]{x-7}$.  $f(x)$ is a cubic function but $f(g(x)) = (g(x))^3 + 7 = (\sqrt[3]{x-7})^3 + 7 = (x-7) + 7 = x$ and that is certainly *not* a cubic function.....  Any $f(\sin x) = (\sin x)^2$ is neither a square function (it has no $x^2$ component) nor a trig function.

Answer (score 1):

Writing conventions can get tricky if you don't define them properly.

Whenever you square a function, it is understood that you're multiplying the function by itself.  In this case, when you multiply $\sin x$ by itself, you get $(\sin x)^2$.  Most people write $(\sin x)^2$ as $\sin^2 x$ for the sake of convenience, so long as they understand it means multiplying the sine function twice.

However, when this convention is misinterpreted, there could be problems.  For example, the inverse sine of x (the angle to which the sine is $x$) is sometimes written as $\sin^{-1} x$.  To the people familiar with that convention, it's fine, but those not familiar could misinterpret this as $\dfrac {1}{\sin x} = \csc x$, which is finding the reciprocal of the sine of x, *not* the angle whose sine is $x$.

The better conventions to define the inverse sine of the function would be as follows...

- defining $\sin^{-1} x$ as the inverse sine of $x$,  while $(\sin x)^{-1}$ is the reciprocal of $\sin x$
- defining $\arcsin x$ as the inverse sine of $x$, which makes it clear that we're looking for that angle.